# Sql two line intersection

Tags: sql, visual-studio, line-intersection

I'm working on a geo project and have some question about that. I draw line with latitude longitude data like the picture below. **1,2,3** are the position I get from db. I want to draw line on that route (**A,B** are the start and end of the line) and get the intersection data (**intersection position** or **distance to the A or B**) from that. What is the **rational way** for this process?

[image]

Comment: Please try to make the question as clear as possible. What is the role of A and B? Are they both given, together with 1, 2, 3? Distance to the A or B of which object?

Comment: A and B are the position I chose from the project. They are random positions. After creating the line, I will chose A and B. Distance of the intersection position to the A or B. For example the intersection is in the middle of the A and B line so the distance of the intersection position to the A or B will be half of the lenght of the A-B line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coordinate geometry functions. Good sample and documentation here: http://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html
You have 2 line, you need to check both with A-B.

Comment: So you fully understood the question?

Comment: The question not clear (finding probability of A-B or finding intersection points), but the solution going same way.

Comment: Thank your for you answer but I just want to know is there any intersection function, method in sql or visual studio.

Comment: I don't think so, you need must develop your own.